# How to get selected text from DevTools code editor?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to get selected text from codeeditor of DevTools. I can get selectionInfo in onSelectionChanged handler, but I dont know how to get text.

Also how to get selectionInfo (current selection) before onSelectionChanged fired?

```js
chrome.devtools.panels.sources.createSidebarPane(
   "title",
    function(sidebar) {
        function update(selectionInfo) {
            //alert([selectionInfo.url, selectionInfo.startLine, selectionInfo.endLine, selectionInfo.startColumn, selectionInfo.endColumn]);
            sidebar.setObject(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectionInfo)));
            // How to extract text using data from selectionInfo ???
        }

        update(/*selectionInfo should be there*/);
        chrome.devtools.panels.sources.onSelectionChanged.addListener(update);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback of `chrome.devtools.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.addListener` doesn't take any argument, cf the [API documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels.html#event-ElementsPanel-onSelectionChanged). That means that your `selectionInfo` will always be undefined.

To get the selected element, you can use the `$0` variable. Your code would therefore look like this:

```js
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane(
   "title",
    function(sidebar) {
        function update() {
            sidebar.setExpression("$0");
        }

        update();
        chrome.devtools.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.addListener(update);
    }
);
```

Note: I replaced `chrome.devtools.panels.sources`, which doesn't exist, by `chrome.devtools.panels.elements`.

Comment: chrome.devtools.panels.sources exists and allow to attach listeners of selection changing in codeeitor.
(Probably you are using some old browser?... I'm using Chrome 32.0.1671.3)

selectionInfo also is defined and contain 5 properties:
selectionInfo.url, 
selectionInfo.startLine, 
selectionInfo.endLine, 
selectionInfo.startColumn, 
selectionInfo.endColumn.
But selectionInfo.selectedText is really missed...

Comment: I'm using Chrome 30.0.1599.101 (stable channel), so indeed I missed that one. Looking at the Chromium source code, it doesn't look like selectionInfo has a selectionText attribute, cf https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/23904024.